# How do you remove an item from child collection in KnockoutJs with TypeScript class

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

My goal has been to create a TypeScript class and bind it as my Knockout model.  Everything works find but the remove which is rendered from the array.  When I look at the debugger in the function the value for this isn't the class of the method that's been called, it's the value of $data that was passed into the method.  What changes are needed so I can pass the child element into the parent and remove it from the array?  I've read about putting a reference to the parent on the children but I'm hoping there is a better way.  Thanks in advance.

```
    <div class="box-head">
        <h2 class="left">Tags</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Tag" data-bind="value: newTag, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>

        <button data-bind="click: AddTag">+Add</button>

        <ul data-bind ="foreach: tags">
            <li class="tagItem">
                <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="tag-edit">Edit</a>
                    <a href="#" class="tag-delete" data-bind="click: $parent.RemoveTag">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

class Tag {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string) { }
}

class TagManager {

    private data = [
        new Tag(1, "Ball Handling"),
        new Tag(2, "Passing"),
        new Tag(3, "Shooting"),
        new Tag(4, "Rebounding"),
        new Tag(4, "Dribbling"),
    ];

    tags: KnockoutObservableArray<Tag>;
    newTag: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    constructor() {
        this.tags = ko.observableArray(this.data);
        this.newTag = ko.observable("");
    }

    AddTag(): void {
        if (this.newTag() !== "") {

            this.tags.push(new Tag(this.tags().length + 1, this.newTag()));

            this.newTag("");
        }
    }

    RemoveTag(tag: Tag): void {

        //I can't call this.tags here because 'this' referes to tag
        var removed = this.tags.remove(tag);
    }
}

$(function () {
    var tagManager = new TagManager();
    ko.applyBindings(tagManager);
});
```

Comment: You might find this video helpful to understand `this` : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Answer (score 2):

Use an arrow function so typescript captures the "this" instance

```
RemoveTag = (tag: Tag) : void => { this.tags.remove(tag; }
```

Comment: This has worked for me. `public removeModule = (module: DashBoardModule): void => {
        var self = this;
        self.modules.remove(module);`